# Android Studio int pass to textview

Tags: java, android, textview, integer, sharedpreferences

I want to show the score at the end of the section with a textview in the AlertDialog. I tried everything but couldn't do it.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

int score;
TextView scoreText,scoreTextt;
AppCompatButton btn_success;
AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
SharedPreferences preferences;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        score = 0;
        SharedPreferences myScore = this.getSharedPreferences("current_score",MODE_PRIVATE);
        score = myScore.getInt("current_score",score);
}

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                timeText.setText("Zaman : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                timeText.setText("Süre Doldu ! ");
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

                for (ImageView image : imageArray) {
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                int x = 0;
                if (score < 10){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("SCORE", score);
                    //Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    showAlertDialog(R.layout.my_success_dialog);

                }
                else if (score >= 10){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("SCORE", score);
                    Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    //showAlertDialog(R.layout.my_success_dialog);
                }


            }

        }.start();




    }

//I want to show textview in AlertDialog.

    private void showAlertDialog(int myLayout){
        builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View layoutView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(myLayout,null);

        builderDialog.setMessage("asd" + score);
        AppCompatButton dialogButton = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.buttonTamam);
        builderDialog.setView(layoutView);
        builderDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog = builderDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

// I'm increasing the score in this section
public void skoruArttır(View view){

        scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        score++;

        scoreText.setText("Skor: " + score);

        SharedPreferences myScore = getSharedPreferences("current_score",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myScore.edit();
        editor.putInt("current_score",score);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

my_success_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/baseline_check_circle_24" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Success"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_success"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.444"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_success"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Skor : "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonTamam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Okey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.123"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_success" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.872"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_success" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1-I tried to show it with text view where the score increased.

scoreTextt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsuccess);
scoreTextt.setText("Skor: " + score);

2-I tried with SharedPreferences without the score reaching 10

3-I tried creating a different public method and writing it in the code.

public void increasingScore(){

}

Comment: have you tries `String.valueOf()` method? you just need to pass your score in it.

Comment: You have invalid IDs in the activity class and in the XML . Can you fix this?
Looks like it's not the whole code.

Comment: scoreTextt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSuccess);
                    scoreTextt.setText("Skor: " + score);

when i try this i get an error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @TwitchArşivim
There is no TextView with ID `textScore` in your XML `my_success_dialog`.

I see that there are two texts with IDs `textView3` and `txt_success`.
You are trying to reference an object that is not declared in your XML